# Has EWS through o365 changed the way it handles SSLv3 connections?

Tags: ssl, .net-4.0, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I've found a problem in my application which means that something is unknowingly (to me) changing:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.SSl3;
```

It appears that in spite of this, my EWS Managed API integration has been working fine for some time, but I am now getting consistent WebExceptions:

```
The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

I'm working to fix up our application to ensure that `SecurityProtocol` is set correctly to `SecurityProtocolType.Tls` but given that it is a global setting within the AppDomain it is not a quick fix.

[This o365 blog post](http://blogs.office.com/2014/10/29/protecting-ssl-3-0-vulnerability/) suggests that Microsoft are planning to remove SSLv3 support (presumably in light of the POODLE vulnerability) - **but does anyone know if there have been recent changes affecting the SSLv3 support in EWS**?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how recently this has happened, but outlook.office365 has fully disabled SSL V3.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=outlook.office365.com&hideResults=on&latest

says...

TLS 1.2 Yes 
TLS 1.1 Yes
TLS 1.0 Yes
SSL 3 No 
SSL 2 No

Comment: That's interesting.  But if it was fully disabled I would not expect to be able to do anything when using `SecurityProtocolType.SSl3` when connecting to EWS...